How did Russia manage to get $300 billion of assets trapped in the West?
G7 aims to use frozen Russian assets to help 'desperate' Ukraine

STRESA, Italy May 25 (Reuters) - The G7 will explore ways to use the future income from frozen Russian assets to boost funding for war-torn Ukraine, finance chiefs from the Group of Seven industrial democracies said on Saturday, but offered no details of how to do so.
The G7 and its allies froze some $300 billion of Russian financial assets, such as major currencies and government bonds shortly after Moscow invaded its neighbour in February 2022.

It's got to be extremely obvious even prior to the invasion that the G7 and its allies are going to freeze all Russian financial assets they can. How did Russia still manage to get $300 billion worth of assets trapped in the West? Why didn't they repatriate all that money prior to invading?
